# JavaScript framework and JSON Schemas

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I came across this question and was quite baffled. I could not understand the underlying thoughts behind this. I have done some API intergation using AngularJS usng `$http` and `$resource` when its RESTFul, but these two questions was something like a puzzle. I want to understand this in detail.

> Does the JavaScript framework you choose support a model abstraction
>   with REST integration? If so, what schema does it expect the JSON
>   replies to use?

Can anyone explain me the two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries expect your REST API to return specifically structured result. ([HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS), ...)

By default, `$resource` works best with HAL, but it can easily be extended to support other types of return formats (https://github.com/jmarquis/angular-hateoas)

Comment: but in reality that's still the server api dictating the schema, not the client side framework as per the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question is asking about something like [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) which allows you to convert the JSON object from the server to your own internal object (abstracted model).

If you use the object from the server throughout your code, and that object's schema changes (e.g. `email` string changes to `emails` array), you may have to change your code in many places.  But if you've mapped the server data to a local object, you may only need to change the mapping (e.g. set internal `email` to first value from server `emails`).